# -Get the selected row item from Datalist-

Tags: asp.net

may I know how to get the selected item in datalist? For eg, I'm displaying a list of food items in a datalist with food name, price, type, a button(Click to order). Now I wanted to click on the selected button and get that specific food name, price & etc from the datalist.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ItemCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemcommand.aspx) event,
take a look at this tutorial: [Custom Buttons in the DataList and Repeater](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/custom-buttons-in-the-datalist-and-repeater-vb)

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
   DataList1.SelectedIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
   Label1.Text = ((ImageButton)DataList1.SelectedItem.FindControl("ImageButton1")).ImageUrl.ToString();

}
```